# Why address register postincrement is (A0)+

Tags: assembly, 68000

Basically in the assembly language of 68000 to postincrement an address register you have to do:

```
(A0)+
```

Example

```
MOVE (A0)+,D0
```

This will move into `D0` the value pointed by address of `A0` and also will increment `A0` by 1.

Considering that `(A0)` is the value pointed by `A0` wasn't better if the postincrement syntax was:

```
(A0+)
```

? Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MOVE.L (A1)+,D0 ; increments A1 by 4, because it is long operation
                ; and 4 is size of long
```

I think that current postincrement syntax points at this feature, while
`(A1+)` more suggests that A1 incremens by one always.

Look at: [Indirect addressing with postincrement](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/68000_Assembly#Indirect_addressing_with_postincrement)

Comment: + inside would suggest that it is preincremented.

Comment: @JensBjörnhager  But the predecrement syntax is the same kind, -(A0), so this can't have been the intention. Pre- and post are differentiated by the position of the operator.